# KnockoutJS: update view model when a user copy'n' paste into a text field?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application, knockout-2.0

I have a same question i.e KnockoutJS: How to update view model after a user copy'n'paste into a text field? and i have gone thought the solution. It is helps me also. But i have one problem with that solution.

When user copy and paste , it will automatically update to model. But it is not clear the value even i make it to empty.

```
 - Ex:Product.OrderNumber("12345") when user click "Clear" button, it is not clear values from textbox. 
Code: Product.OrderNumber("")

valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']
```

the above solution is working in > I.E 8 but is not working in I.E8. Please provide me best solution for that issue.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: What have you tried?  What is not working?  Recreate the issue in a dFiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` instead of `valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']`.